# Battery option is disappeared from control centre

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, ventura, control-center

I want to enable **Show Battery in Menu Bar**, but the battery option is missing in Control Center, I'm using MacBook Pro macOS Ventura 13

[image: Screenshot of the Control Center settings in macOS Ventura]

Comment: It shows for me between Accessibility and Hearing. Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: Yes, multiple times but the result is identical , I have tried third party app like clean my mac of battery status but still no luck.

Comment: Don't use CleanMyMac. I'd just wait for the next OS update, and see if that fixes it. It may be a bug.